# Implicit FTP connection fails first attempt, then succeeds - FIN,ACK sent mid-way through connection

Tags: networking, ftp, wireshark

Our FTPS (implicit) site is working for most customers, however there is one particular company that is unable to connect on the first attempt from their Auto FTP solution (which pulls files from an Outbound folder and deposits files into an Inbound folder within the FTP site). After this initial failure, it waits 30 seconds before it retries, and then proceeds to work without fail.

Using Wireshark, I captured the failing connection and found that the client is sending a `FIN,ACK` to the server immediately after the initial handshake.
[image: Failed connection]

The company that is attempting to connect is insistent that the issue is down to a problem on our end. What could be causing the client to send `FIN,ACK` immediately after the TCP handshake?

Comment: It could be a buggy client I suppose so you might verify what FTPS implicit server service and version you are using and find out what FTP client software and version they are using and see if there are any bug patches related to the two. Perhaps someone simply needs to update to the latest client that resolves connection bugs.

Comment: I can suggest it, however I attempted to discover what FTP client their software used and it was never revealed. Our FTPS server is fully up to date.

Comment: Some FTP servers can log the client version detail, etc. Check your server to see if you already have this logged in the portions with their IP address and the other correlated sessions. You may already have this or you may be able to enable logging of this per connection to your server on the server and get it that way. If you can setup to emulate their environment, then perhaps that'll help you troubleshoot rather than needing someone on their side establish a connection, check the logs, etc.

Comment: Trying to give you some idea that you may find helpful here. I've felt this sort of pain before too unfortunately. If you're using firewall filtering or proxying software that these connections are going thru (or perhaps router ACL rules) those may be worth looking at logs as well for the IP address with the issue.